# AttributeError: Unknown property colour: Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using below code to visualize my algorithm. but I am facing issue with following error.

> AttributeError: Unknown property colour

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
regression = LinearRegression()
model = regression.fit(X_train,Y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)

plt.scatter(X_train,Y_train, colour = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, preds, colour = 'blue')
plt.title('salary vs experiance')
plt.xlabel("years")
plt.ylabel("salary")
plt.show()
```

Comment: "Facing issue"? What issue? Maybe include the desired actions, what should happen, a screenshot of what is wrong (if it is a plot or image of sorts), the error you get, if you get one, and basically everything else you should put in a question here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Its `color`, how about checking the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give it as `color` instead of `colour`

```
plt.scatter(X_train,Y_train, color = 'red')
```